# Pronouncing the letter "е"

Tags: произношение

I'm studying Russian through the Foreign Service Instutute course [available here](https://fsi-languages.yojik.eu/languages/oldfsi/languages/russian.html).

I'm confused about the pronunciation of the letter e. In lesson 1, it says the following about the pronunciation of the letter e:

> 1. In Russian the vowels e and я are given full pronunciation only when they 
>      are stressed.

Then

> 2. When unstressed these vowels are pronounced as a short i.

So what I understood was: "Pronounce e as "ye" when they are stressed, otherwise pronounce them as an "i".

But this can't be right, as then I found words in the prepositional case where I hear the unstressed e being pronounced as "ye". Examples below:

живёте
Москве

I looked up [a previous question about the pronunciation of e](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/1449/pronunciation-of-%D0%B5) and it seemed to suggest that what's happening is that the previous consonant is palatalized and the e is still pronounced as Э.

So am I hearing the e as "ye" even though it's being pronounced as Э with a palatalized consonant? Or is there some rule that I am missing?

Comment: The Е in Москве is stressed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**There're two aspects to their pronunciation: 1) reduction 2) "threshold"**

These aspects are complementary and not mutually exclusive, so must be considered in parallel.

1) When reduced due to being unstressed (save for Ё which is always stressed) the letters **Я** and **Е** don't sound like themselves but like **И** instead or something in between.

2) As a double phoneme that is with the addition of preceding **[y]** or **[й]** (the threshold) the letters **Я, Ю, Е, Ё** are pronounced at the very beginning of words - **я**блоко [**йа**блоко], **е**хать [**йэ**хать], and after **Ь** and **Ъ** - семь**е** [cим**йэ**], съ**е**л [с**йэ**л].

<sup>In the cited rule 1 'full pronunciation' apparently stands for the letter's alphabetic pronunciation (aspect 1 above) with no regard for the threshold (aspect 2 above), which the rule author probably didn't take into account.</sup>

In **Москве** since
1) **[e]** is stressed it is NOT reduced - **масквЕ** instead of **масквИ**
2) it's not placed at the beginning and neither follows **Ь** or **Ъ**, it  doesn't have a threshold, thus **масквИЭ** instead of **масквЙЭ**.      **масквЕ** = **масквИЭ**

In **живёте** since
1) **[e]** is unstressed it is reduced - **живётИ** instead of **живётЕ**
2) it's not placed at the beginning and neither follows **Ь** or **Ъ**, it  doesn't have a threshold, thus **живётИ** instead of **живётЙИ**.

(pronunciation of **Ё** in **живёте** could be analyzed in a similar fashion, which i leave to yourself as an assignment)

Comment: Saying it reduces to (и) is perhaps not a very good way to describe it. For English speakers (i)/ (ih) is much closer than и. The vast majority of  reference books support this. In reality only Russians think it's close to и—because that's your reference point :) But for English speakers it's just (i) as in (it). For reference— https://books.google.no/books?id=A9rrVMQ-PxsC&printsec=frontcover&dq=ward+pronunciation+of+russian&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjEg6PEl6vdAhWIuIsKHaJnD8kQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=ward%20pronunciation%20of%20russian&f=false

Comment: one salient feature of Russian grammarless spelling in writing is replacing E's in unstressed position with И's, but in fact the reduced phoneme is in grey zone, it's a neglected E so to speak, when its proper pronunciation isn't cared for, a withered E... no, there's no Й after T, if sometimes it sounds that way, it's a side effect and not to be emulated, careful pronunciation will rather tend to restore the unstressed E

Comment: You say that it is "живётИ instead of живётЙИ". If that's the case, why does it sound like <ye> at the end (I am hearing the pronunciation at https://forvo.com/search/%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%91%D1%82%D0%B5)

Comment: @edoreld hi, no they don't mix in the Й in there, not sure why you get such an impression, if anything they don't reduce E enough apparently because they pronounce the phrase in isolation and endeavour to pronounce it intelligibly

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка As I said it's almost identical to English (i). As for the second comment, yes, that's right. I was thinking about something else.

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка The main problem with using И as the symbol for reduction is that English speakers usually don't make a proper Russian И. English E is very different from both ы and и, whereas [i] is almost identical to reduced Russian е, и, я

Comment: i don't disagree with you, as they say in Russian: вам виднее, because without being a native English speaker it's difficult to assume their perspective, but speaking of И i don't envision English E or any English phoneme for that matter, so for students of Russian it may be useful to grasp how И is pronounced, then apply it to reduction

Comment: if we're to compare, to my ear И is very similar to the English EE/EA, in **clean** and **клин** the [i] phonemes sound fairly similar save for duration, while differ in **list** and **лист**, again save for duration, since into Russian the English word would be more accurately transcribed as [лыст]